# Elasticsearch - ignore fields from indexing document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have simple question. I'm indexing JSON files that contains several fields into Elasticsearch. How to say ElasticSearch to **ignore** (don't index and store them at all) group of defined fields from the incoming file OR to work only with defined group of fields? Is this possible by using the mapping?

For example: I have JSON files like this:

```
{
    "id": 123456789,
    "name": "Name value",
    "screenName": "Nick name",
    "location": "Location value",
    "description": "Description text",
    "url": "url value",
    "anotherField": 456789,
    "status": null,
    "anotherField2": "9AE4E8",
    "color": "333333",
    .......
}
```

And now I want to Elasticsearch works only with fields (for example) "id;name;description;location;status;url" and ingnore other fields.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: How are you loading those documents in ES? Via logstash?

Comment: I'm sending them from another JAVA application by using HttpClient one by one.

Answer (score 1):

When you serialize the data into a json using a DTO(POJO), you can mark the fields which you dont want to index using **@Jsonignore** annotation if you are using Jackson serializer/desrializer.

eg: @JsonIgnore
    private Date creationDate;

package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;